# What Circuitry is needed to charge in parallel, but power in series?

Tags: battery-charging, parallel

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsvqoU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've read several other battery posts, and didn't find the answer I was looking for. My question is, can the Diagram I've provide do what I intend it to, or am I missing something fundamental.

I have 2 x 3.7v batteries in series to power an Arduino. I also have a 3.7v charging circuit that I would like to be able to recharge the batteries with. Can I simply use two diodes to block any back voltage/current and then simply switch between connecting the second battery to the charger, or to powering the Arduino.

I don't plan to ever have the unit charging while the Arduino is on, but based on my diagram it would be powered in series while one battery was being charged, if this did happen, could it damage anything?

Thanks, please feel free to throw links at me if there is a place out there that already answered this type of question.

Comment: There's a schematic tool with a button on the editor toolbar. It has proper symbols for batteries, diodes, switches, etc., that will be intelligible to the readers of this site. Quality of answers may depend on quality of question! ;^)

Comment: If I understand your drawing correctly, you have a short between the negatives of the two cells, and also across the terminals of the bottom battery.

Comment: @ Transitor, thanks I didn't know about that feature, it looks a bit complex to me I'll give it a shot. I'm new to all this.

Comment: re: "What Circuitry is needed to charge in parallel, but power in series?"  It looks like your title should be changed to "What circuit design will work best to power an Arduino while simultaneously charging 2 li-ion cells in parallel?"  Note: If you connect everything (2 batts & Arduino) in parallel, then you will need to ensure that your power supply can provide sufficient power (especially when the batts are very discharged) or your Arduino will not power up until the batts charge to a certain level.  You'll also probably want to put a capacitor in your design.

Comment: @zeffur, I'm not trying to power both at the same time, in fact I have these very cheap Chinese charging circuits that only put out 200mA. And the Arduino just happens to be whats being powered now, its really not a factor in the question, just the switching from running series, to charging parallel with a common usb connection. Thanks for the advice, I'm very new to electronics, and even with reading a good bit it still hasn't really "Clicked" yet, as we can see from my diagram lol, when you say add a cap, you mean for conditioning?

Comment: Disregard the capacitor comment for now.  Which model Arduino are you using?  The typical supply recommendation for an Arduino is 9 to 12Vdc, 250mA, so 2 li-ion cells in series won't do the job sufficiently.

Comment: @ zeffur, a nano, Input Voltage (recommended) 7-12 V, Input Voltage (limits) 6-20 V

Comment: Ok... if the Nano requires that little power, then 2 li-ion cells should work.  So, to clarify, you want to power your Arduino with 2 li-cells & then switch it off & then charge 1 or the other li-ion cells with 3.7V?

Comment: When you have a properly laid out schematic, its much easier to read. From my initial look at the circuit and see mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this design, it should work for what you are trying to do:

[image]

Make sure your power supply has a regulated current output & it does not exceed 4.2V.

hth, best regards!

p.s.: This small design modification will automatically switch off power to the Arduino when SW1 is switched down:

[image]

Or better yet, this design does the following:
1.  power from the charger can not be applied to the cells (as shown in the diagram)
2.  when the ganged-switches are switched to the down position, power to the Arduino is disabled & power from the charger is applied to both cells in parallel.

[image]

Comment: A potential problem with this circuit is that if the charger is left connected when the Arduino is switched on then BAT1 will receive charge but BAT2 won't, so the cells will become unbalanced. Also the charger and Arduino do not share a common Ground (might be a problem for eg. charging via USB connection).

Comment: Agreed--which is why I included a note about the charger must be powered off. One could also put in a 4th switch above the 3 other switches which is open in the shown switch mode & closes when SW1 is switched down. It would open or close the top rail between the chrgr & BAT1. That would prevent charging of BAT1 in the shown switch mode & permit charging of both batts when switched to charge mode. That extra switch should also eliminate the ground situation that you described. Refer to the redesign added above ^^.

Answer (score 0):

In your top circuit the upper cell is shorted out when the switch is 'off'. In the lower circuit the lower cell is permanently shorted out! The diodes don't do anything useful, but will prevent the charger from working properly.

You cannot have the cells of a battery connected in series and parallel at the same time - you must switch **both** ends of the cell to get from one configuration to the other. In your circuits the cells are hard-wired in series (+ to -) and so cannot be switched to parallel.

The circuit below uses a DPDT switch to change from parallel to serial and turn on the load. The switch must be a 'break before make type' to avoid shorting out while changing over.

The charger must be able handle 8.4V on its output. If it can't then you could use a triple pole switch, a mechanical interlock that forces the switch off when you plug in the charger, or a circuit that detects the higher voltage and disconnects the charger when the load is switched on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdle3J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yeah the goal is to run in series, but then be able to switch to parallel for charging. I don't need to run at the same time. The easy solution is just buy one of these http://tinyurl.com/jjrnhft. But this makes it specific to things powered by USB, and I don't really learn anything. Plus I have the parts already though I felt I could do it myself.